# append object to another object in php

Tags: php, variables, object, append

I have this object:

```
foreach(range(1,$oc->num_users) as $num) {
    $user = 'user' . $num;
    $$user = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT user".$num.", user".$num."_ready,  FROM oc_db WHERE leader='".$_SESSION['username']."' "));
```

This gives objects named user1..X

later I have a simular function like this, where I use the `$$user->$user` that represent a username to connect to the db to get additional information.

```
   $$user = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT x, y, z FROM user_db WHERE username='".$$user->$user."' "));
```

This also makes objects named user1..X, but instead of replacing the object created earlier I want to append this values to the object I created in the first function. `$$user` is the name of the objects. I would like to do something like `$$user .= fetch_object` in the last function, but off course it's not that simple.

Comment: Have you considered using arrays? `$user[1..x]['stuff']`, `$user[1..x]['otherstuff']`

Comment: And that's not the only alarm bell ringing. E.g. sending one structurally identical query except the user.$num part per row you want to fetch is ...suboptimal. And even having `$oc->num_users` ...yeah, could be, but could also be unnecessary, maybe even error-prone. Maybe you should describe the problem you want to solve and ask for a good/efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to append one object to another you simply need to iterate through the first object and then assign each property you find to the second one:

```
$tmp = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT x, y, z FROM user_db WHERE username='".$$user->$user."' "));

foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
    $$user->$key = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a couple of asides, if you are trying to access the `user` property of the object, then you should use `$$user->user`, as `$$user->$user` will be trying to access a numbered property (e.g. for object `$user12`, you're trying to access `$user12->user12`). I would also consider using an array, as fredley suggested (i.e. use `$user[$num]` instead of `$user = 'user'.$num`).

To approach your original question, instead of using the `.=` concatenation assignment operator, you could try adding a method to your `user` class, such as `append`, then using it to append the fetched object to your current object like `$user->append( fetch_object(...));`. In the `append` method, you can define your own rules for how a fetched object is added to your current user object.